# Почему долго не проверяют предложенные переводы на Traducir?

Tags: поддержка, локализация, traducir

Десять дней назад предложил несколько переводов на Traducir:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и они до сих пор не одобрены. В чём дело?

Comment: Запасайтесь терпением, моё самое старое предложение [весит уже 2 месяца](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkevE.png).

Comment: А есть баг-репорт о необходимости этих переводов? Так-то строк много непереведённых, но на сайте они могут быть не видны, поэтому переводить их преждевременно. Если наблюдается отсутствие перевода на сайте, то стоит сначала завести баг-репорт с описанием того где что и как, а ответом (или даже в самом вопросе) предложить переводы со ссылками на traducir.

Comment: И не забудьте про тревоги, которые просил ставить @αλεχολυτ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотреть отдельно в список переведённых, но не утверждённых строк внутри Traducir не особо актуально. Новые переводы нужны для того, чтобы покрывать какой-то имеющийся функционал на сайте. Функционал, который могут "потрогать" пользователи. Т.е. решение в первую очередь начинается с появления вопроса на Мете, описывающего [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) в части [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) на сайте. Такой вопрос должен описывать проблему, чтобы её можно было легко повторить (увидеть наличие непереведённых, т.е. английских, слов). В идеале это прямая ссылка на нужную страницу с отсутствующими переводами. Это также упрощает процедуру завершения цикла дефекта. Модератор может легко проверить готовность и  добавить метку [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be).

Вопрос нужен для того, чтобы решать действительно существующую на сайте проблему. Потому как часто в Transifex/Traducir попадают строки, перевод которых не будет виден на сайте, т.к. нужный функционал просто недоступен. Например, много строк характерных для Stack Overflow for Teams; ранее так же просачивались строки из Documentation (функционал, который был только на enSO, но даже там его прикрыли) и т.д. Также, иногда просачиваются вр*е*менные строки или строки с явными ошибками. Такие строки будут изменены в оригинале и делать для них перевод преждевременно, это будет пустой труд.

Comment: При таком подходе строки, связанные с банами например, могут долго висеть непереведенными, ибо активные участники их редко видят (ну, я надеюсь, что редко...) Нужно стремиться к переводу всех строк, мусор из Teams добавить в игнорированные, а остальные переводить.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight про какие именно строки речь?

Comment: Вроде таких: https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=suspended&translationStatus=2 Думаю, большинство из них используется, но редко на виду, поэтому они висят непереведенными.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight заблокированные должны страдать :) кстати, даже в этом списке есть нерелевантные строки, характерные для staging ground — функционал, которого нет на руСО.